# How to determine if it is a fault of the Network Card?

Tags: networking, pipe, gentoo, network-interface, ping

Basically, I have a PC having problems. Let's call it **POO**.

**POO** is a pc running Gentoo Linux, with KDE. It is quite freshly setup on an old hardware. So far I do not notice it has other problems, until now.

There are mainly two problems.

1. When I `ssh 123.123.123.123` (another Gentoo machine, **HOME**, in another network) from **POO**, it connects without problems. But after a while, the connection breaks with the error `packet_write_wait: Connection to 123.123.123.123: Broken pipe`.

I suspect if the **HOME**'s network's router is blocking the SSH connection, or the **POO**'s network's router is blocking the outgoing traffic.

Then I setup two more machines in the same network of **POO**, namely an Android JuiceSSH **MOBI** and Window 7 PuTTY SSH **WIN**. Both use SSH to connect to **HOME**, and issue the commend `ping -i 10 -D www.gentoo.org` at **HOME**. Both tested for up to 300 packets and gets 0% packet loss!

2. When I issue the commend `ping -i 10 -D www.gentoo.org` at **POO**, I get around 50% packet loss. The lost packets are not sequential. They are randomly occur in between successful packets. (Note that I am issuing ping from POO solely. If I SSH to HOME and issue the ping from there, it gets the `Broken pipe` error as well.)

I also suspect that the `iptables` in **POO** is blocking the traffic. But when I check `iptables -L -n -v`, there is no rule! To remove this concern, I `/etc/init.d/iptables save` and `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`. But the same `Broken pipe` and `packet loss` problems still occur.

It is quite sure that the **POO** pc is having problems. But how to determine which part is having the problem? The hardware network card or the software configuration? By any way I can further investigate into the problem?

---

Sorry to add, I forgot to mention there is a third problem:

3. Sometimes, when I do `ping -i 10 -D www.gentoo.org`, it returns the error `ping: unknown host www.gentoo.org`. It is so weird that it only *sometimes* return this ping error.

Comment: Did you try basic connection troubleshooting like inverting the network cables and ports used to compare the outcome?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tested with different Lan cables and ports, exchanging between **POO** and **WIN**. The results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have figured out what the problem is! It is most likely because of an IP Conflict ._. Sorry to bother you guys.

After I have switched from fix IP to DHCP, no packets loss in ping anymore.

Thanks guys. Lesson learned.